# How to display hidden data of one div to another div?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am working on a project where I came across where when I click plus sign the data will hide and the appear in the div next to it.
here is the code:

```
<fieldset class="col-md-4" >
    <legend>Services</legend>
    <div class="col-md-12" >
        <?php
            $id = 0;
            foreach ($servicesname as $val) {
            $id++;
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="font-size: 16px;" id="itemservices<?php echo $id ?>">
            <span style="float:left;" ><?php echo $val[0]['servicename']; ?></span>
            <a  style="float:right;" href onclick="return addSrvToCart('itemservices<?php echo $id ?>')" >
                <strong>&#8377 <?php echo $val[0]['amount']; ?></strong>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" id="id_<?php echo $id; ?>"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

and the code for next div:

```
<fieldset class="col-md-4" >
    <legend>Cart</legend>
    <div style="list-style:none;" class="no-left-padding" id="cart">
        <div class="col-md-12" >

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 no-right-padding" style="background-color:#f3f0f0; padding-top:6px; border:1px solid#ccc">
        <label class="pull-right">/*what should i write here to show the sum */: ₨&nbsp;</label>
    </div>
    <button style="margin-top:10px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" onclick="bookNowAfterFilter()">Book Now</button>
</fieldset>
```

And This the Jquery code:

```
<script>
 function addSrvToCart(elem){
    alert($('#' + elem).html());
    $('#' + elem).hide();

   //return false;
  //what should i write here the show that hidden div   
  document.getElementById('summery);
  return false;
 }
</script>
```

This is the picture and I want to display the data in the Cart div and show the amount

[image]

Comment: where jquery function call i mean how call it like click event or other event ?

Comment: what you want to know i am not getting

Comment: addSrvToCart() kese call hota hey  ??

Comment: when user press Plus sign in services

Comment: document.getElementById("other div id").innerHTML= "hidden div data";

Comment: used this reference

Comment: you got it idea ?? how put data one to other div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change in both HTML and Script to achieve the result

Try like this
**HTML**

```
<fieldset class="col-md-4" >
    <legend>Services</legend>
    <div class="col-md-12" >
        <?php
            $id = 0;
            foreach ($servicesname as $val) {
            $id++;
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="font-size: 16px;" id="itemservices<?php echo $id ?>">
            <span style="float:left;" ><?php echo $val[0]['servicename']; ?></span>
            <a  style="float:right;" onclick=" addSrvToCart('itemservices<?php echo $id ?>')" >
                &#8377<strong> <?php echo $val[0]['amount']; ?></strong>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" id="id_<?php echo $id; ?>"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

and the code for next div:

```
<fieldset class="col-md-4" >
    <legend>Cart</legend>
    <div style="list-style:none;" class="no-left-padding">
        <div class="col-md-12"  id="cart" >

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 no-right-padding pull-right"  style="background-color:#f3f0f0; padding-top:6px; border:1px solid#ccc">
            Total: ₨&nbsp;<label class="" id="sumAmount">0</label>
        </div>
    <button style="margin-top:10px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" onclick="bookNowAfterFilter()">Book Now</button>
</fieldset>
```

**Script:**

```
function addSrvToCart(elem){
    var div=$('#' + elem);
    div.hide();
    $('#cart').append(div.html());
    var total = parseInt(div.find('strong').html()) + parseInt($('#sumAmount').html());
    $('#sumAmount').html(total);
}
```

It will produce output as

[image]

I think it will help you.

Comment: thanx it helped alote

Comment: @abhinandan-dutt if my answer helped u, then please upvote my answer...

Comment: Deepak- this helped a lot but can you help me a little more- when service move to cart now "the cart have minus sign and when I press that it move back to its previous place"